# File downloaded with POI is corrupted and does not store the data with the popup

Tags: java, html, servlets, apache-poi

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

    public class ExcelWriter extends HttpServlet {
        private void writeExcel(List<Book> listBook, String excelFilePath)
                throws IOException {
            Workbook workbook = getWorkbook(excelFilePath);
            Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

            int rowCount = 0;

            for (Book aBook : listBook) {
                Row row = sheet.createRow(++rowCount);
                writeBook(aBook, row);
            }

            try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    excelFilePath))) {
                workbook.write(outputStream);
            }
        }

        private void writeBook(Book aBook, Row row) {
            Cell cell = row.createCell(1);
            cell.setCellValue(aBook.getTitle());

            cell = row.createCell(2);
            cell.setCellValue(aBook.getAuthor());

            cell = row.createCell(3);
            cell.setCellValue(aBook.getPrice());
        }

        private List<Book> getListBook() {
            Book book1 = new Book("Head  Java", "Anot Serria", 79);
            Book book2 = new Book("Effective Java 1", "Bnot Bloch", 36);
            Book book3 = new Book("Clean Code 1", "Cnot Martin", 42);
            Book book4 = new Book("Thinking in Java 2", "D Eckel", 35);

            List<Book> listBook = Arrays.asList(book1, book2, book3, book4);

            return listBook;
        }

        private Workbook getWorkbook(String excelFilePath) throws IOException {
            Workbook workbook = null;

            if (excelFilePath.endsWith("xlsx")) {
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            } else if (excelFilePath.endsWith("xls")) {
                workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "The specified file is not Excel file");
            }

            return workbook;

        }

        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

            try {
                String excelFilePath = "C:\\Users\\A7369241\\Desktop\\Temp.xls";
                response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="
                        + excelFilePath);
                ExcelWriter excelWriter = new ExcelWriter();
                List<Book> listBook = excelWriter.getListBook();
                excelWriter.writeExcel(listBook, excelFilePath);
                System.out.println("Excel file written successfully");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

public class Book {
    private String title,author;
    private float price;
    public Book(String title, String author, float price) {
        super();
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.price = price;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

So in the ExcelWriter file, as specified the file should be downloaded at the specified file path. A popup is generated in the browser but the Excel file that opens up is corrupted and does not store the hardcoded data. On the other hand the data is in the Excel file at the specified location which does not appear in the popup and the EXCEL FILE IS IN COMPATIBILITY MODE.

Can someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            ExcelWriter excelWriter = new ExcelWriter();
            List<Book> listBook = excelWriter.getListBook();
            excelWriter.writeExcel(listBook, excelFilePath);
            System.out.println("Excel file written successfully");

            String excelFilePath = "C:\\Users\\A7369241\\Desktop\\Temp.xls";
            response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=temp.xls");

            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int length;
                while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
            }
            out.flush();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

If you want just to create excel you have no need to use response. And the filename should be of xlsx type. That's why you have message of compatibility mode.

```
try {
            String excelFilePath = "C:\\Users\\A7369241\\Desktop\\Temp.xlsx";
            ExcelWriter excelWriter = new ExcelWriter();
            List<Book> listBook = excelWriter.getListBook();
            excelWriter.writeExcel(listBook, excelFilePath);
            System.out.println("Excel file written successfully");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

If you still have problems that means your servlet doesn't work properly. Just try to create class with main method and in main method type:

```
String excelFilePath = "D:\\Temp.xls";
Test excelWriter = new Test();
List<Book> listBook = excelWriter.getListBook();
try {
    excelWriter.writeExcel(listBook, excelFilePath);
    System.out.println("Excel file written successfully");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```